# How to refresh a background image depending on the proximity of a beacon?

Tags: swift, xcode, beacon, proximity

I want to change the background image of my app, depending on the proximity of a beacon. If I run the app (see code below) on my iPhone, it shows the background image correctly depending on the proximity - but if I move, it doesn't change/refresh the background image.
I tried the same with a background color (see code below) and it worked: the app changes its background color depending on the proximity of the beacon, and if I move it correctly changes/refreshes the background color. Just the background image doesn't work properly.

How can I force the background image to refresh correctly?

```
func updateDistance(_ distance: CLProximity) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8) {
        switch distance {
        case .unknown:
            let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "1.jpg")
            //backgroundImage.reloadInputViews()
            backgroundImage.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
            self.view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)
        //print("nothing here..")
        case .far:
            let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            //backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "2.png")
            backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "3.png")
            //backgroundImage.reloadInputViews()
            backgroundImage.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
            self.view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)
        case .near:
            let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "4.png")
            //backgroundImage.reloadInputViews()
            backgroundImage.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
            self.view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)
        case .immediate:
            let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "5.jpg")
            //backgroundImage.reloadInputViews()
            backgroundImage.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
            self.view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)
        @unknown default:
            // fatalError()
            let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "6.jpg")
            //backgroundImage.reloadInputViews()
            backgroundImage.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
            self.view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)
        }
    }





func updateDistance(_ distance: CLProximity) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8) {
        switch distance {
        case .unknown:
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
            print("nothing here..")
        case .far:
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        case .near:
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        case .immediate:
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
//          self.sendUserNotification()
        @unknown default:
            <#fatalError()#>
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You are inserting all images at zero index, First remove previous image as if it contains any image like switching between proximity will insert many images all at zero and last one will appear. Or Just add it as subview and bring to front(if needed) instead of inserting at zero.

  - Color is working because you view will have one color. Images are appending one by one. for better understanding try view debugging.